# Next.js image from public folder not loading on dynamic Paths

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic, next.js

I currently started working on Next.js and I'm not sure if I am doing things right.
Currently I have a problem with loading static images from public folder.

[image: this is my Next project]

All the images in public folder are loading in any path except register/confirmation/[email].js dynamic path

[image]

This is how I am importing images in Navbar
[image]

and this is how I import Navbar in all the pages inside of _app.js

[image]

The problem is not only in the Navbar, its just whenever I go to dynamic path /register/confirmation/[email].js images.

I don't know what the problem is i tried creating Media,static,images file in public changed import directories many times but nothing works.

One more thing , image paths are /_next/static/media in all paths but in dynamic path it becomes /register/confirmation/_next/static/media.

Thanks whoever helps!

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just added "/" before my image name and it solved the problem.

```
<Image
 src="/Logo.svg"
 width={200}
 height={100}
 alt="Logo"
 priority={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

its not necessary to load static images like this you can use next/image component.

```
 <Image
    src="/me.png"
    alt="Picture of the author"
    width={500}
    height={500}
  />
```

Comment: yes i know! but then i need to give it width and height that i didnt want.

Comment: @OgLuka I have the same issue.  having to specify the width in the HTML violates the rule that such characteristics should be specified in CSS.  it's bad design on the part of NextJs